# My notes say a torus and a sphere homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I have the following definition for a **torus**

$I = [0, 1]$

$I^2 = I \times I$

$T^2 = I^2 / \sim$ where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation generated by

$(0, t) \sim (1, t) \ \forall \ t \in I$

$(s, 0) \sim (s, 1) \ \forall \ t \in I$

Then I have the following defintion for a **sphere**

$X = \{(3 + \cos(t))\cos(s), (3 + \cos(t))\sin(s), \sin(t)) \in \mathbb{R^3}, s,t \in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R^3}$, a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$

This will give us unit a sphere centered at $(3, 0 ,0)$

Now my notes say $T^2$ and $X$ are homeomorphic. But I have read numerous times that this is not true. So where is the problem? Is $T^2$ actually a torus? Here's the (awkward looking using Latex) visual I have in my notes for $T^2$, which makes me think it's a torus?

----->>-----

$| \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \           |$

^ $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $         ^

$| \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \           |$

----->>-----

Comment: Your definition of the torus is the standard one, and indeed a torus is not homeomorphic to a sphere. The easiest way to see this is via the Fundamental Group: Any loop on a sphere contracts to a point while you can find a loop on the torus that does not contract to a point. Some other ways are via Euler Characteristic or Homology groups. Unfortunately a justification by point-set topology isn't coming to mind at the moment.

Comment: in your coordinates for $X$ the second comma should be removed, otherwise you are in $\mathbb{R}^4$!

Comment: Actually I'm wondering about the definition of the torus. We don't say anything about the points in the torus that are not boundary points of $I^2$. We have defined two equivalence classes for the edges of the plane, but we have not mentioned an equivalence class for the points inside the plane? Is this implicit?

Comment: There is no equivalence relation imposed except on the boundary. Think about a circle: It's what you get by identifying $0$ and $1$ in the closed unit interval $[0,1]$. You get a homeomorphism $f$ from $[0,1]/\sim$ to $S^1$ by writing $f(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$, and noting this descends to a continuous bijection (therefore homeomorphism — why?) on the quotient.

Comment: It is common when describing equivalence relations to not describe the whole relation but instead to specify what amount to generators, and then implicitly $\sim$ is the smallest equivalence relation containing those pairs. For example, if we describe an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ by $x \sim x + 1$ for all $x$, the full equivalence must of course include $x \sim x$, $x+1 \sim x$, $x \sim x+2$. This is a bit of a contrived example, since it could be described by $x \sim x + n$ for all $x$, all integers $n$. In particular for a point not mentioned, the equivalence class is just itself.

Answer (score 3):

The parametric surface you've described is not a unit sphere centered at $(3,0,0)$, but is instead a torus where the radius of the central circus of the torus is three, and the radius of a cross section of the donut is 1.

Comment: How does this work? Unless I just misread, $X$ lies entirely in the plane $x=y$.

Comment: @EricStucky is right. There are some typos going on here. If the second coordinate of the parametrization of $X$ were to have $\sin(s)$ instead of $\cos(s)$, then $X$ would indeed be a torus obtained by rotating a circle of radius $1$ about an axis $3$ units from its center.

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: OK, @sonicboom, so the only mistake left is in thinking that $X$ is a sphere. Erase that and you have only to show that $T^2$ is homeomorphic to $X$. There should be an obvious homeomorphism to write down, using the letters $s,t$ and throwing in $2\pi$, as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you plot $$X = \{(3 + \cos 2\pi t)\cos \ 2\pi s, (3 + \cos \ 2\pi t)\sin \ 2\pi s, \sin \ 2\pi t) \subset \mathbb{R^3}\colon s,t \in [0,1]\}$$ (slightly modified from what you have) you obtain the graph

[image]

which is a torus rather than a sphere.